# Why are non-null type properties of class obtained from WeakReference.get() changing to nullable

Tags: android, kotlin, weak-references, android-handler

I am trying to write a Handler in an Activity that needs a reference to the activity. If I write like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val mHandler = MainActivityHandler(this)

    class MainActivityHandler(val activity: MainActivity) : Handler() {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
            when(msg?.what) {
                MSG_CHANGE_TEXT -> {
                    activity.tv_logged.setText(R.string.title_main)
                    activity.mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(SOMETHING), 3000)
                }
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code compiles and works as expected. But if I try to pass a weak reference to the activity like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val mHandler = MainActivityHandler(WeakReference(this))

    class MainActivityHandler(val activityRef: WeakReference<MainActivity>) : Handler() {
        private val activity
            get() = activityRef.get()

        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
            when(msg?.what) {
                MSG_CHANGE_TEXT -> {
                    activity?.tv_logged.setText(R.string.title_main)
                    activity?.mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(SOMETHING), 3000)
                }
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the compiler complains that **tv_logged** and **mHandler** are nullable receiver type and need to be accessed using ?.
I can understand that the `val activity: MainAcitivity?` inside the handler is nullable because it comes from WeakReference.get() but how come the properties in MainActivity are also nullable?

Answer (score 1):

Its because the return type of `activity?.tv_logged` is (assuming its a `TextView` ) , TextView? . In Kotlin docs , where an alternative is proposed to checking `null` via `if` condition

> Your second option is the safe call operator, written ?. 
>   b?.length
>   This returns b.length if b is not null, and null otherwise. The type of this expression is Int? .

To perform a certain operation only for non-null values, you can use the safe call operator together with let:

```
 activity?.let{ //access activity via `it`}
```

Comment: It works. I can access tv_logged in let block without the safe call operator. But how does tv_logged (or mHandler) change to Non-null type inside activity's let block? Why are tv_logged and mHandler nullable when accessed using activity?. but non-nullable when accessed inside the activity?.let{} block?

Answer (score 0):

I understood this when I read the whole text at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls

This has nothing to do with WeakReference as I suspected. It happens because safe call operator returns a nullable type even when accessing non-nullable type properties. (The doc doesn't really specify this as explicitly and clearly.)